# Using Cucumber to test a RESTful service, how can I capture a value to use in a future RESTful method?

Tags: rest, cucumber, automated-tests, bdd, restful-authentication

I have a `RESTful` method that returns some `JSON`, say

```
{
   "A":"B",
   "C":"D"
}
```

And I need to use the value of "C" (here, "D") in the next RESTful call to validate it. But, without knowing what the value is ahead of time (ie, it is a UUID, so I can't guess it)

How can I do this with `Cucumber` syntax?

A good reference for more info like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of cuke testing of rest services. You are welcome to look at some of my stuff inside my [rest_baby gem](https://github.com/dmcnulla/rest_baby/tree/master/features)

```
myuuid = JSON(response.body)["C"]
```